# Languages used to design a custom map with navigation (Google Maps)

Tags: maps

I've got a project in mind (Finding cars in a parking using a local map based on a gps location), i'm trying to gather resources and see if the project can be realised.

At some point I will need to create several custom maps but i dont know which language to use to create awesome and professional maps.

Please, any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your target platform? Target audience? Do you have any favourite programming languages? Do you have experience with desktop GIS tools?

Comment: Let me explain the project more in details;

The idea is to control a parking of a mall via a system (sensors on each parking bail to indicate the state of bail and having a gps location) and application to support the system.

So basically, at the entrance the app will provide to you the map of the parking with available bails, to choose one and you reserve the parking for 5 minutes, the map navigator will help you to find the reserved bail.

The same idea will be used to find a parked car.

So, I've got knowlegde on arduino and sensors, on ionics 2 aslo for apps. But nothing on maps

Comment: Are you asking how to start building an ionic app with a map inside it?

Comment: Yes but a custom map. i will have to draw the parking by my own. so its gonna a map yes but a personnalised one.

Comment: Edit your question, add that information, rephrase everything. What do you want to know *exactly*?

Comment: I have a parking schema that i want to transform into a map and integrate that map in my application.

The question is since i do not know any languages that people uses to create/design maps, I would like to know which language/tools to use to create your own customized map with navigation based on location